# Как убрать дублирование при наследовании в sass?

Tags: css, sass

Есть код sass

```
%btn{
  font-size:12px;
  background:#cecece;
}
.header_btn{
  @extend %btn;
  width:100px;
}
```

он конвертится в такой вод css

```
.header_btn {
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #cecece;
}

.header_btn {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы был всего один селектор, в котором расположатся все эти свойства, ведь если так оставить это очень фигово(

Comment: Чем это фигово?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам, скорее всего, кажется, что sass жрет лишние байты. В этом микропримере это действительно так, но просто @extend работает не так, как вы ожидаете: вместо того, чтобы пихать свойства extend'а в каждый селектор, он пихает селекторы к одному extend, чтобы не повторять код:

```
.s
  unicorn: true

.b
  @extend .s

.d
  @extend .s
```

->

```
.s, .b, .d {
  unicorn: true; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=t.css.map */
```

В случае, когда наследуется кусок хотя бы на сотню байт, это дает очень некислую экономию, нежели пихать эти свойства в каждый селектор.

Answer (score 0):

Автогенерируемые файлы (а css, сгенерированный sass - это именно автогенерированный файл) не предназначены для прочтения человеком. До тех пор, пока в браузере эта таблица стилей работает так, как предполагалось - нет никаких причин "исправлять" ее.

Comment: 1. А в браузере стили смотреть? 2. Лишний объём.

Comment: Лишний объем? Во-первых, CSS можно минифаить, попробуйте скопировать свой код из вопроса в http://cssminifier.com/, например. В том числе полно скриптов для минифая на продакшене. Во-вторых, текстовый контент так и так в 90% случаев передается сжатым gzip от сервера к браузеру.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Минифицирование скидывает все пробелы, энтеры, коментарии. Алгоритм минификации складывает свойства в один селектор если он повторяется?(использую gulp-minifycss)